# Force WRAP by last space, not for first

Tags: html, css

Can I force the WRAP for the last space, and not the first?

Example:

```
<div>
<div>
This test orange
</div>
<div>
This test green
</div>
<div>
```

When the screen is minium, the wrap is between "This" and "test".
It's possible to force to be between "test" and 'color'?

Just to solve a problem with web header.
It's more beautiful break the last (designers...)

Comment: Hello. A fiddle to reproduce would be perfect. Your question as is doesn't make sense to the majority of the people reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encapsulate "test color" on a span and apply a `display: inline-block;`...:

HTML:

```
<div>
<div>
This <span>test orange</span>
</div>
<div>
This <span>test green</span>
</div>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
span{
    display: inline-block;
}
```